# When I make multiple requests using jQuery, I can't see the responses until everything ends. Even in Console.log

Tags: php, jquery, simultaneous, ajax-request

I'm trying to recover some long data from the server. In paralel I have another request (PHP) that runs once per 5 seconds.

Function that runs more than one time:

```
var monitor = setInterval(monitorar, 5000);

function monitorar(){
  $.get('ferramentas/monitor.php').done(function(data){
    $("#conteudo").html(data);
  });
}
```

Function that run just one time:

```
function buscar_dados(){
  $.post('ferramentas/login_sistema.php', function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

The problem is that the div #conteudo doesn't receive any data until the second function ends. Than everything blows up in the div. Can I receive the request of the first function in parallel?

Comment: Are you by chance fetching session data?

Comment: What do you mean by "blowing up in the div"?

Comment: use a setTimeout, and have the function fire itself in the complete or always callback method of the request in another setTimeout

Comment: I agree, sounds like a blocked session. Just get the information you need and close it as soon as possible (in both of the scripts).

Comment: Why not, Rooster? Is something wrong?

Comment: @JulianoBarreto You will get multiple parallel requests if one or more don't finish in 5 seconds. That could cause older information to overwrite newer information making the whole thing very unreliable.

Comment: I'm kinda confused. maybe is too late in the night. what do you mean by (second function ends)?. i don't see a 2nd function any were in relation to monitorar.

Comment: I understand. The data from the first function are retrieved from the session. Until I close the session the request is locked? Is it right?

Comment: Correct.  In your "long running script" you will need to call `session_write_close()` and then right afterwards `session_start()`.  This will allow access to the session data in your other script that is firing every 5 seconds.

Comment: @jeroen I know that and I'll set the setInterval a longer time. But I put 5 sec for test purposes

Comment: @Crackertastic I'll try this and post here the results. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JulianoBarreto It's not about the time, but the method. Using a timeout and setting a new one in the callback function is far better.

Comment: @jeroen Ok. I think that you are right. I'll change the code to timeout.

Comment: @Crackertastic Everything is working now. Again, thank you for your help.@jeroen thank you for your tip.